# IIS Server api 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

Tags: api, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

Good day

Can anyone please assist me I keep getting this error?

I have a website that's running perfectly but the asp.net.core API I have under the website refuses to work, confirmed the file location as well as the file security permissions.

[Image of my sites in my IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmrQI.png)

[API web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rLxI.png)

If anyone can please just direct me as to where else to look to resolve this issue since I have no idea what to do or where to even look.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try below steps to slove this issue:

1. Add the below in web config.

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

2. Please check if there is a default page, or any page named after the default page convention (default.html, default.aspx, etc.), if not, you can add a default page in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
       <add value="myDefault.aspx"/>
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Good day 
I have done as you suggested but now I am getting this error:
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.